# @deviniti/jql-autocomplete-input code is not working

Tags: reactjs

I am using @deviniti/jql-autocomplete-input package for jira jql autocomplete. please anyone help me how to use this component

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@deviniti/jql-autocomplete-input

I have installed that package and tried to build that example code..but I get the following error:

> ./node_modules/@deviniti/jql-autocomplete-input/src/JQLAutocompleteInput.jsx 14:18 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:18) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type. |  |    JqlInvalidIcon()
>   { |     return ( |

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import JQLAutocompleteInput from '@deviniti/jql-autocomplete-input';


class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        inputValue: ''
    }

    fetchbyAxios(resourceUrl) {
        return axios.get(resourceUrl);
    }

    getSuggestionsRequest = fieldName => fetchbyAxios(`/rest/api/2/jql/autocompletedata/suggestions?fieldName=${fieldName}`);

    validationRequest = jql => fetchbyAxios(`/rest/api/2/search?startAt=0&maxResults=1&validateQuery=strict&fields=summary&jql=${jql}`);

    getAutocompleteDataRequest = () => fetchbyAxios('/rest/api/2/jql/autocompletedata');

    onJQLChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            inputValue: event.target.value
        })
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <JQLAutocompleteInput
                getAutocompleteDataRequest={this.getAutocompleteDataRequest}
                getSuggestionsRequest={this.getSuggestionsRequest}
                inputStyle="ak-field-text"
                initialValue={this.props.inputValue}
                inputId={this.props.inputId}
                label={'JQL'}
                onChange={this.onJQLChange}
                setValue={this.props.setValue}
                validationRequest={this.validationRequest}
        />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That package lists the JSX file as the entry point instead of the distro file. You could modify your webpack to process this file, or fork it and correct the entrypoint.

Comment: I tried with create react app & webpack, in both sides I'm getting mentioned issue only. And I tried with changed entry point  to "entry: __dirname + '/dist/JQLAutocompleteInput.js' " inside ./node_modules/@deviniti webpack.config.js file , eventhough I'm getting same issue.. could you please explain in detail which loader I have to use..

Comment: Not your code, the library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue... Please try this import

```
import JQLAutocompleteInput from '@deviniti/jql-autocomplete-input/dist/JQLAutocompleteInput';
```

Answer (score 0):

Im getting this error:

> ERROR in
> ../../../../node_modules/@deviniti/jql-autocomplete-input/dist/JQLAutocompleteInput.js

It seems like @atlaskit/input was not in package.json file, thats why it won't work.

> node_modules@deviniti\jql-autocomplete-input\dist\node_modules
> doesn't exist or is not a directory